# Remove a specific chars in a string

Tags: vb.net, special-characters

I have a code to check whether is there any special characters in a string. If it detected the characters, it will remove the chars only and proceed checking. Or if you have any simpler way, please assist me. Thank you

```
Public Function IsThereAnySpecialCharacter(ByVal str As String) As Integer
        Dim illegalChars As Char() = "~`|@#$^*{}'[]""_<>\".ToCharArray()
        Dim count As Integer
        Try
            count = 0
            For Each ch As Char In str ' to check whether special character exist in a string
                If Not Array.IndexOf(illegalChars, ch) = -1 Then
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ' I want to remove the chars here
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            Next
            Return count
        Catch ex As Exception
            strErrMsg = "Oops! Something is wrong with verify special characters at IsThereAnySpecialCharacter"
            MessageBox.Show(strErrMsg & vbCrLf & "Err: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function IsThereAnySpecialCharacter(ByVal str As String) As Integer
    Dim illegalChars As Char() = "~`|@#$^*{}'[]""_<>\".ToCharArray()

    Try
        For Each ch As Char In illegalChars
            str = str.Replace(ch, "")
        Next
        MsgBox(str)
    Catch ex As Exception
        strErrMsg = "Oops! Something is wrong with verify special characters at IsThereAnySpecialCharacter"
        MessageBox.Show(strErrMsg & vbCrLf & "Err: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return 0
End Function
```